# coordinate transformation

Tags: matrix, transformation

I have two coordinate systems, like so

[image: Picture of coordinate systems]

How can I transform a point on the one of the coordinate system to other ?

Pxyz = M . Px'y'z'    what is M ?

Comment: @kshahar hi, do you know the answer ?

Comment: M is the transformation matrix.. http://www.kwon3d.com/theory/transform/transform.html

Comment: @teodron can you write the answer

Answer (score 6):

From the image it looks like both your coordinate systems are [cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system), where the only difference between the two is that one has a different origin from the other.

If this is the case then to translate from `xyz` coordinates to `x'y'z'` coordinates all you need is a [translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix), i.e.

```
x' = x + dx
y' = y + dy
z' = z + dz
```

Where [dx, dy, dz] is the difference between the origins of the two coordinate systems.

Matrix multiplications always have the origin as a fixed point and so you can't perform translations using a 3x3 matrix, however as a sort of workaround you can express your 3-dimensional coordinates as the 4-dimensional vector `[x, y, z, 1]` and use a 4x4 transformation matrix that includes a translation, e.g.

```
|1 0 0 dx | |x|   |x + dx|
|0 1 0 dy | |y|   |y + dy|
|0 0 1 dz | |z| = |z + dz|
|0 0 0 1  | |1|   |   1  |
```

You can then ignore the 4th component to get the translated 3D coordinates.  See more on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_matrix#Matrix_representation)